# Repeat based off user input OS X

Tags: bash, shell-script, brace-expansion

I am creating a script which asks a user to enter a message then how many times they would like to display that message.

This is what I have so far.

**`message.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -en "Enter a message to display: "
read -r MESSAGE

echo -en "How many times would like to repeat it? "
read -r REPEAT

for i in {1.."${REPEAT}"}; do
 echo "${MESSAGE}"
done
```

**Actual Output**

For example, if I enter ***Hello*** for the message and ***5*** for the number of repeats it will only display ***Hello*** only once.

**Expected Output**

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

How can I make it repeat based off the user's input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of precedence. Brace expansions are evaluated *before* the variable is:

```
$ foo="10"
$ echo {1.."$foo"}
{1..10}
```

Or, with more detail:

```
$ set -x
$ echo {1.."$foo"}
+ echo '{1..10}'
{1..10}
```

This is documented in `man bash`:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion,
>   parameter    and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command
>   substitution    (done  in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting;
>   and pathname expansion.

In other words, when you try use `{1..$foo}`, the first thing that bash will do is attempt to evaluate the brace expansion. At this point, the variable hasn't been replaced with its value yet, it is simply `$foo`. Therefore, what bash sees is equivalent to `{1..SOMESTRING}`:

```
$ echo {1..SOMESTRING}
{1..SOMESTRING}
```

Since this is a question of the order in which the shell performs certain operations, there is no workaround. You simply can't use variables in that way within brace expansion. You'll have to find a different way to do it. For example, use `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 "$REPEAT"); do
    echo "${MESSAGE}"
done
```

Or:

```
for((i=0;i<=$REPEAT;i++)); do 
    echo "${MESSAGE}"
done
```

Comment: I used your last example and it works perfectly! Thank you very much :)